# A recursive relation for the number of well formed nested parentheses of length $n$ and depth $\leq d$

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relation, recursion

Consider a function $C(n, d)$ which counts the number of well formed, i.e, balanced, parenthetical 'words' of length $n$ and maximal nested depth $\leq d$.

That is, $(())$ has $n = 4, d = 2$. $()((())())$ has $n = 10, d = 3$ and so on.

$C(n, d)$ counts all well formed strings above (i.e, $($ and $)$ are balanced), of length *exactly* $n$ and depth *at most* $d$ (that is, smaller depths are allowed).

There should be a recursive expression for $C(n, d)$.

The base cases are easy enough:

$C(n, d) = 0$ if $n$ is odd regardless.

$C(n, d) = 0$ if $d = 0$ but $n> 0$

$C(n, d) = 1$ if $d = n= 0$ (the empty string)

Now for the recursive step.

I've been thinking about this but there are a lot of overlap which makes things difficult.

For instance, I first guessed $\sum_{i}\sum_j C(n- i, d-j)C(i, j)$ That is, you mixing all strings of length $i$ with strings of length $n-i$ should give you strings of length $n$. I think the depth in general will remain $\leq d$ without problems. But the problem with this approach is that I'm pretty sure there will be plenty of double/extra counting of the same strings more than once.

I have a few other candidates but again I think they largely double count in general.

I was also thinking if I could express it solely in terms of $C(n-2, d-1)$ as ${n-2 \choose 2}C(n-2, d-2)$ (placing $(, )$ at any positions in an $n-2$ string) but then this misses out on potential $d$ depth strings. But doing ${n-2 \choose 2}C(n-2, d)$ might inculcate depth of $d$.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/151111/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/72064859/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $w$ is a well-formed parenthetical word of depth at most $d$. Then either $w = \epsilon$, or $d > 0$ and $w = (x)y$, where $x$ is a parenthetical word of depth at most $d-1$, and $y$ is a parenthetical word of depth at most $d$; furthermore, the decomposition is unique.